# Converting JavaScript into PHP code: Is year a leap year?

Tags: php

The function should take a date as its parameter and return `true` or `false`. Here is a JavaScript model of what I need:

```
function isLeapYear(date) {
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    if (year % 4 == 0)
        if ((year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    else
        return false;
}
```

This is what I have so far, but it isn't working well:

```
function isLeapYear($date){
    $time = strtotime($date);
    return date('L') ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm  new to this site.  What do you mean by that?  I think I did format it correctly.

Comment: @Lobita: When you originally posted your question, some of the code was not indented and not formatted as code. It's fixed now. (I don't know if you saw it, but there's a little `{}` button that formats a block of code as code.)

Comment: That doesn't look like a conversion to me...

Comment: I know, I am missing a lot.  I am just very new to this.  I didn't get too much experience with javascript before.

Answer (score 2):

Date-function requires the timestamp as second parameter, e.g:

```
return date('L', $time) ? true : false;
```

Otherwise you're checkimg whether this year, 2012, is a leap year. According to your method signature, that's not the required behaviour.